# Unable to remove index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, constraints, ddl, erwin

When the user activates the FK index removal option, DDL is generated for it, and when the PK index removal option is activated, the DDL is created for this application.

Two tables were created with the example below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE3] 
(
    [COL] [VARCHAR](20) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE3]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLE3]
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([COL] ASC)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE4] 
(
    [COL] [VARCHAR](20)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE4]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TABLE3_TO_TABLE4]
        FOREIGN KEY ([COL]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TABLE3] ([COL])
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO
```

If you select both the Delete FK Constraints option and the Delete FK Index option
The following syntax is generated.

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE4]
    DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS [FK_TABLE3_TO_TABLE4]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE3]
    DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS [PK_TABLE3]
GO

DROP INDEX [dbo].[TABLE3].[PK_TABLE3]
GO
```

An error occurs for the DROP INDEX syntax here.

> SQL Error [3701] [S0007]: Index 'dbo.TABLE3.PK_TABLE3' does not exist or you do not have permission to drop it.

My question is:

1. If SQL Server removes the constraint, will the index be removed as well?
2. The `DROP INDEX` statement can use `IF EXISTS` to prevent an error, but I know that `IF EXISTS` is supported from SQL Server 2014 or 2016.

Since the 2005 version of the application under development needs to be supported, the `IF EXISTS` syntax does not seem to be a clear solution.

Please advise on what to do.

For documentation for each version of SQL Server, refer to the following links.

SQL Server 2005: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms176118(v=sql.90)

SQL Server 2008: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms176118(v=sql.100)

SQL Server 2012: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms176118(v=sql.110)

Comment: In the beginning, you have to eliminate the connection between the two tables. With this command you can do this. Executing the second command also deletes the index. Please try one. I did and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code:**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TABLE4 DROP CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE3_TO_TABLE4
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TABLE3 DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE3
Go
```

You can use following code to get you constraints name list in your database:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_TYPE,CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

OR

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_TYPE,CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE LOWER(TABLE_NAME) <> N'sysdiagrams'
```

| TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | CONSTRAINT_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE3 | PRIMARY KEY | PK_TABLE3 |
| TABLE4 | FOREIGN KEY | FK_TABLE3_TO_TABLE4 |

Comment: This is not the answer I want.

The answer you advised is to remove the constraint, my question about removing the index is not solved.

Comment: In the beginning, you have to eliminate the connection between the two tables. With this command you can do this. Executing the second command also deletes the index. Please try one. I did and it worked.

Comment: Eliminating the relationship became. But my question seems to be that if you remove the relationship (constraint), the index is also removed.

When SQL Server removes a constraint, will the index be removed as well?

Comment: Yes. At first you should remove the relation ship. then you can do any thing you want.